# POST with single parameter returns 404 error

Tags: c#, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass a single parameter to a Web API POST method.

Following is my AJAX call:

```js
$http({ method: 'POST', url: "customers/ProcessCustomer/" + customerId })
    .success(function (data) {

    });
```

where `customerId` is a `Guid` .

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("customers/ProcessCustomer")]
public void ProcessCustomer(Guid id)
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

But I only get a *404 not found* error when I do this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're adding the parameter in the query string. That's not how POST works

Comment: @Jonesy `customerId` is not part of the query string, it's part of the path.

Comment: @Stijn You're right.  Web API is able to convert that to the POST parameter.  Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using attribute routing but you haven't specified an `id` parameter in the route. Use this instead:

```
[Route("customers/ProcessCustomer/{id}")]
```

See [Attribute Routing in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

When you `POST` to an action method, the data isn't embedded in the URL. Instead, use the `data` field of the settings object in your ajax call:

```
// I didn't recognize what library you're using for the AJAX call, so this is jQuery
$.ajax('customer/ProcessCustomer', {
    data: { id: customerId },
    success: function() { /* woohoo! */ }
});
```